# Haml: How to add classes dynamically to an element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a `<tr>` element in my view, and I want to add classes dynamically on this element depending on an association between two models (many to many between company and packaging).

The result should looks like

```
<tr class="pck1 pck3 pck5">
```

where `pck1`, `pck3` and `pck5` are packagings associated with a company.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

or simply:

```
%tr{ :class => classes }
```

Answer (score 3):

Say you have an array `classes = ['pck1', 'pck3', 'pck5']` with the classes you want your `tr` to have.

Just type something like:

```
%tr{:class => classes.join(' ')}
```